# Deriving suc iszero pre functions from alternative definition of natural number

Tags: lambda-calculus

Here I am given an alternative definition for natural numbers.

Like this

$$
LET \ \widehat{\underline{0}} = \lambda x. x
$$

$$
LET \ \widehat{\underline{1}} = (\underline{false}, \ \widehat{\underline{0}})
$$

$$
LET \ \widehat{\underline{2}} = (\underline{false}, \ \widehat{\underline{1}})
$$

$$
\vdots
$$

$$
LET \ \widehat{\underline{n+1}} = (\underline{false}, \ \widehat{\underline{n}})
$$

$$
\vdots
$$

I am given a task to derive $\widehat{\underline{suc}}, \ \widehat{\underline{iszero}}, \ \widehat{\underline{pre}}$ such that

$$
\widehat{\underline{suc}} \ \widehat{\underline{n}} = \widehat{\underline{n+1}}
$$

$$
\widehat{\underline{iszero}} \ \widehat{\underline{0}} = \underline{true}
$$

$$
\widehat{\underline{iszero}} \ (\widehat{\underline{suc}} \ \widehat{\underline{n}}) = \underline{false}
$$

$$
\widehat{\underline{pre}} \ (\widehat{\underline{suc}} \ \widehat{\underline{n}}) = \widehat{\underline{n}}
$$

Here's my try:

I came up with:

$$
\widehat{\underline{iszero}} = \lambda n. n \ \underline{true}
$$

$$
\widehat{\underline{suc}} = \lambda n. (\underline{false}, n)
$$

$$
\widehat{\underline{pre}} = \lambda n. \underline{snd} \ n
$$

And here's to show they meet all requirements:

(i) $\widehat{\underline{suc}} \ \widehat{\underline{n}} = \widehat{\underline{n+1}}$

$\widehat{\underline{suc}} \ \widehat{\underline{n}} = (\lambda n. (\underline{false},n))\widehat{\underline{n}} = (\underline{false},\widehat{\underline{n}}) = \widehat{\underline{n+1}}$

(ii) $\widehat{\underline{iszero}} \ \widehat{\underline{0}} = \underline{true}$

$\widehat{\underline{iszero}} \ \widehat{\underline{0}} = (\lambda n. n \ \underline{true}) \widehat{\underline{0}} = \widehat{\underline{0}} \ \underline{true} = (\lambda x. x) \underline{true} = \underline{true}$

(iii) $\widehat{\underline{iszero}} \ (\widehat{\underline{suc}} \ \widehat{\underline{n}}) = \underline{false}$

$\widehat{\underline{iszero}} \ (\widehat{\underline{suc}} \ \widehat{\underline{n}}) = \widehat{\underline{iszero}} \ \widehat{\underline{n+1}} = (\lambda n. n \ \underline{true}) \widehat{\underline{n+1}} = \widehat{\underline{n+1}} \ \underline{true} = (\underline{false}, \widehat{\underline{n}}) \underline{true} = (\lambda f. f \ \underline{false} \ \widehat{\underline{n}}) \underline{true} = \underline{true} \ \underline{false} \ \widehat{\underline{n}} = (\lambda xy. x) \underline{false} \ \widehat{\underline{n}} = (\lambda y. \underline{false}) \widehat{\underline{n}} = \underline{false}$

(iv) $\widehat{\underline{pre}} \ (\widehat{\underline{suc}} \ \widehat{\underline{n}}) = \widehat{\underline{n}}$

$\widehat{\underline{pre}} \ (\widehat{\underline{suc}} \ \widehat{\underline{n}}) = \widehat{\underline{pre}} \ (\widehat{\underline{n+1}}) = (\lambda n. \ \underline{snd} \  n) \widehat{\underline{n+1}} = \underline{snd} \ \widehat{\underline{n+1}} = \underline{snd} \ (\underline{false}, \widehat{\underline{n}}) = \widehat{\underline{n}}$

Here $\underline{snd} \ (a,b) = b$.

Are the steps correct and reasonable? Thanks a bunch!